# in the perception of the time

Tags: meaning, grammar

Dear every body!

Can anyone help me about the following passage? The words in bold are intended:

Given the speed and extent of Russia's recent imperialistic expansion, **in the perception of the time**, “today's inner Orient” was “yesterday's outer Orient” and “today's outer Orient” could potentially become “Russia's inner Orient of tomorrow.”

It is from a book about  imperialistic expansion of Russia nearly 120 years ago. The meaning of this passage is clear, but the role and meaning of the phrase "in the perception of the time" in it is ambiguous.

Of course, I have another question. After getting Answer, how can I express my thanks to those who have answered me?
Thanks a million.

Comment: _The time_ here means "the historical period"

Comment: The way to express your thanks is to upvote helpful answers, and accept the best correct answer. You can, and in most cases should, upvote the answer you accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means, "as things were perceived in that time."